# problem in pandas 'apply' function to replace missing values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, fillna

I want to replace `np.nan` values with other value in `pandas.DataFrame` using 'apply' function. And I will use `replace` method that where NaN is replaced with max value of each column (axis=0). You better understand below.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[1, np.nan, 3],
                  'b':[np.nan,5,6],
                  'c':[7,8,np.nan]})

result = df.apply(lambda c: c.replace(np.nan, max(c)), axis=0)
print(result)
```

There are three `np.nan` values. Two of them is replaced with appropriate values, but just one value is still `np.nan`(below picture)

[image]

After setting argument `axis` to `1`, there is still one value that isn't replaced. What's the reason?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Python's `max` doesn't work if a list starts with NaN; so `max(df['b'])`returns `NaN` and it cannot fill the NaN value in that column. Use `c.max()` instead (which works because by default `Series.max` skips NaNs). So:

```
df = df.apply(lambda c: c.replace(np.nan, c.max()), axis=0)
```

But instead of `replace`, you could use `fillna` on axis:

```
df = df.fillna(df.max(), axis=0)
```

Output:

```
     a    b    c
0  1.0  6.0  7.0
1  3.0  5.0  8.0
2  3.0  6.0  8.0
```